# Inapproximability result implies apx-hardness?

Tags: complexity-theory, approximation

If an optimization problem is known to be inapproximable up to some precision, does this automatically imply that the problem is apx-hard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If P$=$NP then there is a polytime algorithm for any NP optimization problem, and so *every* problem is APX-hard. So from now on, suppose that P$\neq$NP.

We can associate with any decision problem $L \in NP$ an optimization problem $o_L$ by defining $o_L(x) = 1$ if $x \in L$ and $o_L(x) = 2$ otherwise. Suppose $o_L$ reduces to $o_M$ via a PTAS reduction $(f,g,\alpha)$ (notation as in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PTAS_reduction)). Let $C = 1+\alpha(1/2)$. Thus if $y$ is a $C$-approximation to $o_M(f(x))$ then $g(x,y,1/2)$ is a $3/2$-approximation to $o_L(x)$, from which we can determine whether $x \in L$ or not. Altogether, this gives a polytime reduction from $L$ to $M$. Now take any NP-complete language for $L$ and any NP-intermediate language for $M$ (such a language exists because of Ladner's theorem). On the one hand, since $M \notin P$, you cannot 2-approximate $o_M$. On the other hand, $L$ doesn't reduce to $M$ (since that would apply that $M$ is NP-complete), and so $o_L$ doesn't reduce to $o_M$. We conclude that $o_M$ is *not* APX-hard.

Comment: I don't see why the existence of a PTAS-reduction from $o_L$ to $o_M$ implies the existence of a polytime reduction from $L$ to $M$. Suppose $L$ is the total set and $M$ is the empty set. Let $q$ be the optimal solution for all instances of $o_L$. If $f$ is the identity function and $g$ fulfills $g(y) = q$ for all $y$, then $f,g$ give a PTAS-reduction from $o_L$ to $o_M$: all solutions are optimal in $o_M$, and these $1$-ratio solutions in $o_M$ are mapped into $1$-ratio solutions in $o_L$. Still, due to the definition of $L$ and $M$, there is no many-one polytime reduction from $L$ to $M$.

Comment: Perhaps you need some nontriviality assumption.

Comment: So what condition is needed to ensure that the polytime reduction exists?

Comment: Whatever conditions are needed to make this proof go through.

Comment: For example, it might suffice for $M$ to be non-trivial.

Comment: Maybe that's enough, but I'm still wondering... The problem with a PTAS-reduction is that it doesn't need to map solutions with high value into solutions with high value, but it's enough to map nearly-optimal solutions into nearly-optimal solutions (whatever it means "nearly-optimal" in each problem)...

Comment: Try writing out the proof in full. Perhaps it never works, but perhaps it doesn't work under some mild assumptions.

Comment: Ok, I'd like to try... Did you write your proof from scratch, or did you base your idea on some paper/book I could check out?

Comment: It seems that what you get, on the original languages $L,M$, is a pair of functions $f,g$ such that given an instance $x$ of $f$, you can determine whether $x \in L$ by computing $g(x,[f(x) \in M])$. While that's not quite a many-one reduction, it might still suffice to contradict P≠NP in some circumstances.

Comment: I don't think I based this answer on anything, but it was over 8 years ago...

Comment: Ok, thanks for all the info. Just a quick question about your notation: what do you mean by $[f(x)\in M]$? A solution of $o_M$ should go in this second parameter of $g$, so I guess you mean "any solution proving $f(x)\in M$"?

Comment: It's the truth value of $f(x) \in M$.